# how to combine values in list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of tuples which I want to combine similar values:

This is the list of tuples I've got when I combined multiple lists using `list(zip(a,b,c))`

```
data = [('name', 'id', 'isp', 'num'),
        ('name1', 'id1', 'isp1', 'num1'),
        ('name2', 'id2', 'isp2', 'num2')]
```

I want to group together similar values.

Desired Output:

```
data = [('name', 'name1', 'name2'),
        ('id', 'id1', 'id2'),
        ('isp', 'isp1', 'isp2'),
        ('num', 'num1', 'num2')]
```

Are there any tricks to achieve this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just transpose it:

```
print(list(zip(*data)))
```

Output:

```
[('name', 'name1', 'name2'), ('id', 'id1', 'id2'), ('isp', 'isp1', 'isp2'), ('num', 'num1', 'num2')]
```